# what does element, complexType and sequence mean in WSDL schema?

Tags: soap, wsdl

I understand below code is part of wsdl schema from [this file](https://test.developer.intuit.com/QBWC/TroubleshootWebServiceFS/Service.asmx?wsdl).

```
<s:element name="serverVersionResponse">
   <s:complexType>
      <s:sequence>
         <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="serverVersionResult" type="s:string"/>
      </s:sequence>
   </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

my question is:

1) what is `<element>`?

2) what is `<complexType>`?

3) what is `<sequence>`?

4) most importantly, what does "s" mean in `<s:element>`?

If the data is send back to me. What does the data looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is `<element>`?

In XML Schemas, the element defines an element of the XML.

It could be of simple and compex Type.

> what is `<complexType>`?

CompexType usually contents the Object definition, and it could include one or more elements.

> what is `<sequence>`?

Sequence defines the sequence of XML elements. Its optional thing.
If CompexType surrounded by the  indicator. This means that the child elements must appear in the same order as they are declared. You will learn more about indicators in the XSD Indicators chapter. Though in your example doesn't matter as only one element is there.

> most importantly, what does "s" mean in `<s:element>`?

`s` is local name schema of your Schema URI.

I think you should be taking a deep dive of XML schema definition. You could try https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp.